# Prove that the norm of X is invariant given that X is the solution to a first order differential equation, i.e. X' = AX

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

How do you confirm that the solution of a skew-symmetric matrix, is constant? I tried looking at a solution which goes the other way (norm-preserving -> skew-symmetry) instead of skew symmetry -> norm-preserving. Can anyone offer a way to show this?

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's just compute the derivative of $\|X\|^2$and show that this is $0$. Indeed,

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\|X\|^2=\frac{d}{dt}\left(X^TX\right) &=\frac{d}{dt}(X^T)X+X^T\frac{d}{dt}X\\
&= \left(\frac{d}{dt}X\right )^T X+X^T\frac{d}{dt}X\\
&=X^TA^TX+X^TAX\\
&=X^T(A^T+A)X\\
&=0,
\end{align}
since  $A$ is skew-symmetric. Hence, $\|X\|^2$ is constant.